# How to increase the count individually?

Tags: angular

In my project, there are different individuals who are standing for election and thus want to increase the count of there vote individually. But whenever i am clicking even on a single card all the remaining cards are incremented automatically.Anyone please suggest.

I am using AngularJs 7. 
  Following is the component.html file

```html
<mat-card-actions>
                <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" 
(click)="supportButtonclick()" color="accent" ><mat-icon>thumb_up</mat- 
icon></button>
                <button mat-mini-fab color="accent" 
(click)="unsupportButtonclick()" color="decent" ><mat- 
icon>thumb_down</mat-icon></button>               
                 <div  fxFlex.gt-sm="33.33%" class="card-text">{{ 
numberofSupport }}</div>
                <button mat-button><mat-icon>share</mat-icon></button>
            </mat-card-actions>
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.0/angular.min.js"> 
</script>
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard2',
  templateUrl: './dashboard2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard2.component.scss']
})
export class Dashboard2Component implements OnInit {

  numberofSupport: number=0;
  supportButtonclick(){
    this.numberofSupport++;

  }
  unsupportButtonclick(){
    this.numberofSupport--;
  }

 




 <mat-card-actions><button mat-mini-fab color="primary" 
(click)="supportButtonclick()" color="accent" ><mat-icon>thumb_up</mat- 
icon></button><button mat-mini-fab color="accent" 
(click)="unsupportButtonclick()" color="decent" ><mat- 
icon>thumb_down</mat-icon></button>               
<div  fxFlex.gt-sm="33.33%" class="card-text">{{ numberofSupport }}</div>
<button mat-button><mat-icon>share</mat-icon></button>
</mat-card-actions>
Following is the component.ts file
@Component({
selector: 'app-dashboard2',
templateUrl: './dashboard2.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./dashboard2.component.scss']
})
export class Dashboard2Component implements OnInit {
numberofSupport: number=0;
supportButtonclick(){
this.numberofSupport++;
}
unsupportButtonclick(){
this.numberofSupport--;
}


My expected result is to show the individual count of individual 
candidate, when a button is clicked
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `unique` property, even if it's custom, to do that. 
(I've over-semplified the example so you can understand better).

```
listOfCard  = [
    {
      id: 0,
      name: "card 1",
      count: 0
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "card 2",
      count: 0
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "card 3",
      count: 0
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "card 5",
      count: 0
    },
  ]

  public addCount(id){
    let idx= this.listOfCard.findIndex(el => el.id == id);
    this.listOfCard[idx].count++;
  }

  public decreaseCount(id){
    let idx= this.listOfCard.findIndex(el => el.id == id);
    this.listOfCard[idx].count--;
  }
```

Simple html:

```
<div class="fl" *ngFor="let card of listOfCard">
  <span style="margin-right: 10px">{{card.name}}</span>
  Count: <span style="margin-right: 10px">{{card.count}}</span>
  <button (click)="addCount(card.id)">Add</button>
  <button (click)="decreaseCount(card.id)">decrease</button>
</div>

.fl{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Stackbtliz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uckb2t

Comment: Thank you Jacopo Sciampi sir. This solves my problem.

Comment: Perfect. you can accept this answer if you think this is exactly what you need. Merry christmas.

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too.